# How to fix 'KeyError' when reading a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dataset2.csv', index_col=0) 
print (df)

dataframe1 = df.sort_values('ums', ascending = False)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

ax1.bar(dataframe1.index.dataframe1['ums'])
ax1.set_xticklabels(dataframe1.index, rotation=60, horizontalalignment = 'right', fontsize = '12')

ax1.set_title('Title', fontsize = '22')
ax1.set_ylabel('Text')

plt.show()
```

It should read the .csv file named "Dataset2" but every time I execute the code I keep getting "Exception has occurred: KeyError
'ums'
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\datafile2.py", line 10, in 
dataframe1 = df.sort_values('ums', ascending = False)".

My column in the .csv file has exactly the same name. Here is how the first lines of my file look like:

```
nr  port    country      ums
1   Port1   Australia    47.03
2   Port2   USA          37.47
```

What can I do to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error as well as a sample csv.

Comment: What is `print(df)` or perhaps `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: Print dataframe, it should display the file contents in the console.

Comment: Pandas must not be parsing the file the way you expect. You should include the first few lines of the file in your question. Copy and paste as text and format as code.

Comment: I just added a photo of the first lines in my file.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry, just edited it.

Comment: there's probably one or more spaces in "ums" (e.g. maybe "ums  ")

Comment: I checked it out but there aren't any spaces.

Comment: Try specifying the separator - `pd.read_csv(...,sep='\s+')`.

Comment: Which separator do you mean?

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Answer (score 1):

Usually csv file use comma `,` as default to seperate the names, so the content of your file should be like:

```
nr,port,country,ums
1,Port1,Australia,47.03
2,Port2,USA,37.47
```

Or specify the separator explicitly as commented by @wwii:

```py
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dataset2.csv', index_col=0, sep='\s+')
```

Comment: When I tried specifying the separator, I got the following error: "Exception has occurred: ParserError
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 4, saw 4". And do you mean that I should make the names separated by comma in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue

this is my code, I just simplified your matplotlib codes

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('Dataset2.csv')
print(df)

dataframe1 = df.sort_values('ums', ascending=False)
names = dataframe1['port']
values = dataframe1['ums']

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
plt.plot(names, values)
plt.show()
```

Maybe because you're using raw string when defining the dataset path?

try to remove the `r` and the index_col, as the default pandas `read_csv` will treat the first row as the header

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset2.csv')
```

this is the result from my code
[image: result]

Comment: Good idea! I meant to point out the raw string as well but I got distracted, I hope this helps the OP

Comment: Just tried this code, I still get the error but can I just point the name of my file like that? I mean how will pandas know where it is located?

Comment: @mayft for my example, it's because the dataset file is in the same directory as the python script, but no matter where the file is, as long as you give `read_csv` the correct path, the i/o will be able to read the file.

Comment: I see. Is it possible that it has something to do with the file format (it's UTF-8)?

Comment: If your dataset contains any Unicode, so you can add the `encoding` property when reading the csv `pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Tried it, still not working. May I probably download your file somehow?

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/rosdyana/bb87b65ba764cc21ea3f53f4b452c830